# jquery to wrap elements

Tags: jquery

I have this code and every 3 's I need to wrap with a div

(original)

```
<div id="entries"> 
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
</div>
```

(should become)

```
<div id="entries"> 
<div>
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
</div>
<div>
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
</div>
<div>
<a class="thumbnaila"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="blabla"/></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Think there needs to be more information, is this just straight html or are you generating the html from somewhere else?

Answer (score 6):

I've put together this plugin that does the job nicely

```
(function($){

   $.fn.wrapChildren = function(options) {

    var options = $.extend({
                              childElem : undefined,
                              sets : 1,
                              wrapper : 'div'
                            }, options || {});
    if (options.childElem === undefined) return this;

 return this.each(function() {
  var elems = $(this).children(options.childElem);
  var arr = [];

  elems.each(function(i,value) {
    arr.push(value);
    if (((i + 1) % options.sets === 0) || (i === elems.length -1))
   {
     var set = $(arr);
     arr = [];
     set.wrapAll($("<" + options.wrapper + ">"));
   }
  });
    });

  }

})(jQuery);
```

You pass in an options object defining

- `childElem` - the element nodeType of the immediate children to wrap
- `sets` - how you want to group the child elements. For example, sets of 3 in your case. Default is 1
- `wrapper` - the element to wrap the child elements in. default is `<div>`

Use like so on your test data.

```
$(function() {

  $('#entries').wrapChildren({ childElem : 'a' , sets: 3});

});
```

Here's a [**Working Demo**](http://jsbin.com/idize) to play with. Add **/edit** to the URL to play with the code.

**EDIT:**

<strike>I'm tempted to make this into a more fully fledged plugin, if it proves useful.</strike>.

I've created [**an improved version of the plugin**](http://forloop.co.uk/wrap-child-elements-in-groups-in-jquery)

Comment: Kudos for providing a flexible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Mighty work and might not be the smartest thing to do:

```
var $entries = $("#entries");
var $div = $('<div></div>').appendTo($entries);
while($div.next().length > 0){
  $div.append($div.nextAll().slice(0,3));
  $div = $('<div></div>').appendTo($entries);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to work as intended. It appends a `<div> to the end of the entries `<div>` and then checks that there is a next element, which there wouldn't be, as the `<div>` is appended to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a class to each "sub-div" that fills the content horizontally, and give it clrar:both; as css atribute, and it will display the way you want. In case you want to display it vertically, apply float:left; instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $c = $('#entries');
while ($c.children('a').length) {
    $c.children('a:lt(3)').wrapAll('<div>');
}
```

working demo (albeit with a different HTML structure) at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/sppgP/