# Wrapping a div around every three divs

Tags: jquery

Say I have 6 child divs and they don't have unique identifiers:

```
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
```

With jQuery, I want to wrap every set of 3 with `<div class="parent"></div>`. So it would render as:

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400820/jquery-to-wrap-elements

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wow, nice challenging question =)

```
while(($children = $(':not(.parent)>.child:lt(3)')).length) {
    $children
        .parent()
        .append(
            $('<div class="parent"></div>')
                .append($children.remove())
    );
}
```

#### Edit: Didn't know about the `wrapAll` method, so:

```
while(($children = $(':not(.parent)>.child:lt(3)')).length) {
    $children.wrapAll($('<div class="parent"></div>'));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This should do it:

```
var $children = $('.child');
for(var i = 0, l = $children.length; i < l; i += 3) {
    $children.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<div class="parent"></div>');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/kZ2pm/)

Comment: I like that we both decided `$children` was the most correct name.

Answer (score 4):

There's a small plugin I've written which I use in scenarios like this. It takes a collection, and splits it in to chunks of `x` (where `x` is the size of each chunk):

```
$.fn.chunk = function( cLen ) {
    var chunks = [];
    while ( this.length ) {
        chunks.push( this.splice(0, cLen) );
    }
    return $(chunks);
};
```

It can then be used like this:

```
$('.child').chunk(3).each(function() {
  $(this).wrapAll('<div class="parent">');
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Py2SP/13/)

Or, as a plugin for this purpose:

```
$.fn.wrapEvery = function( cLen, wrapperEl ) {
    while ( this.length ) {
        $( this.splice(0, cLen) ).wrapAll( wrapperEl );
    }
};
```

Which could be used like this:

```
$('.child').wrapEvery(3, '<div class="parent">');
```

#### [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Py2SP/59/)