# XSLT For-Each Wrapping every nth item in a div

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have a series of nodes that are direct child nodes to a parent I want to loop over those nodes but have them wrapped in 'groups' of 4... I'm probably not wording this very clearly so this might help;

```
<span class="child01">@nodename</span>
<span class="child02">@nodename</span>
<span class="child03">@nodename</span>
<span class="child04">@nodename</span>
<span class="child05">@nodename</span>
<span class="child06">@nodename</span>
<span class="child07">@nodename</span>
<span class="child08">@nodename</span>
..
<span class="child32">@nodename</span>
<span class="child33">@nodename</span>
..and so on
```

Goal

```
<div class="group">
<span class="child01">@nodename</span>
<span class="child02">@nodename</span>
<span class="child03">@nodename</span>
<span class="child04">@nodename</span>
</div>
<div class="group">
<span class="child05">@nodename</span>
<span class="child06">@nodename</span>
<span class="child07">@nodename</span>
<span class="child08">@nodename</span>
</div>
<div class="group">
..
<span class="child32">@nodename</span>
</div>
<div class="group">
<span class="child33">@nodename</span>
..and so on
```

I have tried variations on this idea - wrapping the lot in the open and closing group tags and every fourth loop drop in a new close / open pair

```
<div class="group">
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/*">

<span>
<xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
</span>

 <!--
            =============================================================
            After very 4th item  
            =============================================================
            -->
            <xsl:if test="position() mod 4 = 0">
              <xsl:text></div><div class="page"></xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

But essentially it seems XSLT won't let me start with a closing unmatched tag
The clkoset solution I ahve found so far is a 'fix' in jquery [Wrapping a div around every three divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696975/wrapping-a-div-around-every-three-divs) but I would rather not rely on javascript to format the page.

Comment: the reason this wasn't working is that you still have to produce at any moment a well-formed document I think. Unless you told the processor that the output is plain text

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNumCols" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="span[position() mod $pNumCols = 1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="span">
  <div>
   <xsl:copy-of select=
    ".|following-sibling::span[not(position() > $pNumCols -1)]"/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<t>
    <span class="child01">@nodename</span>
    <span class="child02">@nodename</span>
    <span class="child03">@nodename</span>
    <span class="child04">@nodename</span>
    <span class="child05">@nodename</span>
    <span class="child06">@nodename</span>
    <span class="child07">@nodename</span>
    <span class="child08">@nodename</span> .. 
    <span class="child32">@nodename</span>
    <span class="child33">@nodename</span>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<div>
   <span class="child01">@nodename</span>
   <span class="child02">@nodename</span>
   <span class="child03">@nodename</span>
</div>
<div>
   <span class="child04">@nodename</span>
   <span class="child05">@nodename</span>
   <span class="child06">@nodename</span>
</div>
<div>
   <span class="child07">@nodename</span>
   <span class="child08">@nodename</span>
   <span class="child32">@nodename</span>
</div>
<div>
   <span class="child33">@nodename</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Took me a few reads to figure out what you were doing and apply it to my real code. But I got it - I think.

Essentially the initial template (match=/.) is used to call the second template (match=span) but in doing so is applied only to every xth counted child (determined as a variable pNumCols). When the second template is called it uses the passed child value and the grabs its siblings and outputs the sibling set - all while wrapping in the required DIV tag.

Comment: @Elijha: Yes, though the official terminology is slightly different: "*applying templates*" and "*parameter*". The essential is getting the nodes into "groups" -- first defining every starting node in a group, then processing the group as a whole. It is possible to do this kind of grouping on arbitrary node-sets -- where the nodes aren't siblings.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev And it will do the same with every fourth element also by setting $pNumCols to 4?

Comment: guess you're not using modulo 0 because position() is 1-base indexed?

Comment: instead of span[not(position() > $pNumCols -1)] couldn't one use span[position() <= $pNumCols -1] or even simpler span[position() < $pNumCols] ?

Comment: btw, in Altova XMLSpy (RaptorXML engine) I had to use &lt; instead of < in the expression

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis, This answer doesn't use <, it uses >

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev does it play a difference? aren't they both special characters? or does the parser think a tag is starting or something when one uses < ? (I had simplified the logical expression to not use not and subtraction)

Comment: btw, see my alternative using "mode" below

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis, This is something fundamental in XML -- read the Spec. The characters (used as characters) '&' and '<' must be escaped. Otherwise they are considered to indicate the start of an entity-reference or an XML tag -- respectively. This is why I never use `x &lt; y` -- I use instead `not(y >= x)` . Thus the code is much more readable.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev thanks for confirming this is spec'ed. That design choice is probably because they wanted to make a parser that works on character streams with one character look ahead only or something. However it looks like a hack and in my opinion they shouldn't have allowed > too to keep it consistent (transforming a logical expression like I did to make it more readable and less costly in CPU time [assuming they don't simplify it automatically internally as C++ compilers do] shouldn't make it unparseable)

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis, Actually, one needs to escape `>` too, but in very rare cases.

Answer (score 0):

If like me you need to transform the source elements that are being divided by position, use xsl:for-each instead of xsl:copy:

```
 <xsl:template match="span">
   <ol>
     <xsl:for-each select=".|following-sibling::span[not(position() > $pNumCols -1)]"/>
       <li><xsl:value-of select="./text()"/></li>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </ol>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: could also use <xsl:apply-templates select=.../> I guess

Answer (score 0):

Faced by the same problem, that is wanting to output

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">...</div>
    <div class="col"/>...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

from a CXML (Collection XML) file (http://gallery.clipflair.net/collection/activities.cxml - the data behind the PivotViewer display at http://gallery.clipflair.net/activity)

I coined up the following, based on other suggestions here, but **using "mode" attribute of "template" and "apply-templates"** XSL tags instead which make it cleaner I believe:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?altova_samplexml http://gallery.clipflair.net/collection/activities.cxml?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:cxml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/collection/metadata/2009"
  exclude-result-prefixes="cxml"
  >

  <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="COLUMNS" select="2"/>

  <!-- ########################### -->

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>ClipFlair Activities</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ########################### -->

  <xsl:template match="cxml:Collection">
    <div class="container">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ########################### -->

  <xsl:template match="cxml:Items">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="cxml:Item[position() mod $COLUMNS = 1]" mode="row"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ########################### -->

  <xsl:template match="cxml:Item" mode="row">
    <div class="row">
      <div>----------</div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::cxml:Item[position() &lt; $COLUMNS]" mode="col"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cxml:Item" mode="col">
    <xsl:variable name="URL" select="@Href"/>
    <xsl:variable name="FILENAME" select="cxml:Facets/cxml:Facet[@Name='Filename']/cxml:String/@Value"/>
    <div class="col">
      <xsl:value-of select="$FILENAME"/>  ---  <xsl:value-of select="$URL"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ########################### -->

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()|@*">
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output from the above when run in Altova XMLSpy tool (note that it uses altova_samplexml processor instruction to find the XML data) is:

---

```
2DaysInParis-OpenActivity-CapRev-FR-EN.clipflair --- http://studio.clipflair.net/?activity=2DaysInParis-OpenActivity-CapRev-FR-EN.clipflair

Abu_Dukhan-CapRev-A1-AR.clipflair --- http://studio.clipflair.net/?activity=Abu_Dukhan-CapRev-A1-AR.clipflair


----------

AFarewellToArms-RevCap-C2-EN.clipflair --- http://studio.clipflair.net/?activity=AFarewellToArms-RevCap-C2-EN.clipflair

agComhaireamhCountingRND.clipflair --- http://studio.clipflair.net/?activity=agComhaireamhCountingRND.clipflair


----------

Al-imtihan-CapRev-B1-AR.clipflair --- http://studio.clipflair.net/?activity=Al-imtihan-CapRev-B1-AR.clipflair

AlBar-Cap-B1-B2-IT.clipflair --- http://studio.clipflair.net/?activity=AlBar-Cap-B1-B2-IT.clipflair

...
```

Comment: note that if the position() was a 0-based index instead of 1-based one, we'd be using modulo 0, not modulo 1

Comment: also note that I use a simpler expression to get the N-1 siblings following every (N*i)+1 item, where i>=0 than used by other post here, but I had to use lt; instead of < because the Altova RaptorXML parser (included in Altova XMLSpy tool) wasn't accepting it