# xsl - wrap every 2 items in the for-each with a div

Tags: xslt

I have an xsl:for-each and I would like to wrap every 2 items in a div. How to do that?

```
<xsl:for-each select="$datapath/PackageInfoList/PackageInfo">

<!-- lots of html in here -->

</xsl:for-each>
```

So the result would be:

```
<div>
<!-- lots of html in here -->
<!-- lots of html in here -->
</div>
<div>
<!-- lots of html in here -->
<!-- lots of html in here -->
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9908661/2633606).

Answer (score 6):

Select the odd `<PackageInfo>` elements, like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="$datapath/PackageInfoList/PackageInfo[position() mod 2 = 1]">
  <div>
     <!-- lots of html in here -->

     <!-- do something with following-sibling::PackageInfo[1] -->
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This runs for elements at positions 1, 3, 5, etc. Handle the respective first following `<PackageInfo>` manually.

---

More idiomatic

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$datapath/PackageInfoList/PackageInfo" mode="group2" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PackageInfo" mode="group2">
  <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::PackageInfo[1]" />
    </div>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PackageInfo">
  <!-- lots of html in here -->
</xsl:template>
```

More flexible

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$datapath/PackageInfoList/PackageInfo" mode="group">
    <xsl:with-param name="groupcount" select="2" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PackageInfo" mode="group">
  <xsl:param name="groupcount" select="2" />

  <xsl:if test="position() mod $groupcount = 1">
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::PackageInfo[position() &lt; $groupcount]" />
    </div>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PackageInfo">
  <!-- lots of html in here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is for every odd element which is not what I want.

How do I incorporate your 'More idiomatic' answer with a for-each?

Comment: @MarkSteggles Since you did not *say* what you want (i.e. by supplying "current" and "wanted" output samples), it's my best guess. — The idiomatic solution works without `<xsl:for-each>`. Just throw it out and use `<xsl:apply-templates>`. 99% of the time `<xsl:for-each>` is the wrong thing to use anyway, try to avoid it entierely.