# XSLT transformation as chunk of data

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to perform xslt transformation as chunks,I have a input request which contain multiple building inside buildings tag,For each 10 building i need to create a Valuations tag ,set some constant values and map the 10 building values to the location/Address tags Street,Line1 and country.
ie.,if i send 21 building i need to create Valuations tag and transform xml for each split 10,10 and 1 building.Similarly if i send 35 building i need to create Valuations tag for each split 10,10,10 and 5 and transform respectively.
Also i would like to externalise the parameter 10 which iam using as a chunk decider.ie., if i change the parameter as 5 and send 21 buildings it should create 5 Valuations tag for each 5,5,5,5 and 1 building and map the building to locaton values accordingly.

can you please let me know how can i acheive it in xslt.

i have restriction in my application i can use only xslt 1.0

Input XML:

```
<buildings>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>27 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>28 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>29 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>40 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>41 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>42 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>43 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>44 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>45 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>46 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>47 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>48 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>49 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>40 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>41 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>42 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>43 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>44 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>45 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>46 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
<building>
<street>Stewart Place</street>
<addressline-1>47 Stewart Place</addressline-1>
<country>US</country>
</building>
</buildings>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:param name="SplitNo" select="10"/>
 <xsl:template match="/*">
<provider-request>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="building[position() mod $SplitNo = 1]"/>
</provider-request>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="building">


    <Valuations>
    <request>
            <CompanyID>94A7DB70-F90F-4EE7-A614-E548D1045277</CompanyID>
            <Logon>ydahmouni</Logon>
            <CalculateValuation>true</CalculateValuation>
            <ReturnAddedValuation>true</ReturnAddedValuation>
             <Valuation>
               <Locations>

    <xsl:for-each select=".|following-sibling::building[not(position() > $SplitNo -1)]">
<location>
 <Address>
                        <Street><xsl:value-of select="street" /></Street>
                        <Line1><xsl:value-of select="addressline-1" /></Line1>
                        <country><xsl:value-of select="country" /></country>
                     </Address>
</location>
</xsl:for-each>

               </Locations>
            </Valuation>
    </request>
    </Valuations>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```
<provider-request>
   <Valuations>
      <request>
         <CompanyID>94A7DB70-F90F-4EE7-A614-E548D1045277</CompanyID>
         <Logon>ydahmouni</Logon>
         <CalculateValuation>true</CalculateValuation>
         <ReturnAddedValuation>true</ReturnAddedValuation>
         <Valuation>
            <Locations>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>27 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>28 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>29 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>40 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>41 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>42 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>43 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>44 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>45 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>46 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
            </Locations>
         </Valuation>
      </request>
   </Valuations>
   <Valuations>
      <request>
         <CompanyID>94A7DB70-F90F-4EE7-A614-E548D1045277</CompanyID>
         <Logon>ydahmouni</Logon>
         <CalculateValuation>true</CalculateValuation>
         <ReturnAddedValuation>true</ReturnAddedValuation>
         <Valuation>
            <Locations>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>47 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>48 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>49 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>40 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>41 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>42 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>43 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>44 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>45 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>46 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
            </Locations>
         </Valuation>
      </request>
   </Valuations>
   <Valuations>
      <request>
         <CompanyID>94A7DB70-F90F-4EE7-A614-E548D1045277</CompanyID>
         <Logon>ydahmouni</Logon>
         <CalculateValuation>true</CalculateValuation>
         <ReturnAddedValuation>true</ReturnAddedValuation>
         <Valuation>
            <Locations>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>47 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
            </Locations>
         </Valuation>
      </request>
   </Valuations>
</provider-request>
```

Actual Output:

```
<provider-request>
   <Valuations>
      <request>
         <CompanyID>94A7DB70-F90F-4EE7-A614-E548D1045277</CompanyID>
         <Logon>ydahmouni</Logon>
         <CalculateValuation>true</CalculateValuation>
         <ReturnAddedValuation>true</ReturnAddedValuation>
         <Valuation>
            <Locations>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>27 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>28 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>29 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>40 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>41 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>42 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>43 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>44 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>45 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>46 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
            </Locations>
         </Valuation>
      </request>
   </Valuations>
   <Valuations>
      <request>
         <CompanyID>94A7DB70-F90F-4EE7-A614-E548D1045277</CompanyID>
         <Logon>ydahmouni</Logon>
         <CalculateValuation>true</CalculateValuation>
         <ReturnAddedValuation>true</ReturnAddedValuation>
         <Valuation>
            <Locations>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>47 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>48 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>49 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>40 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>41 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>42 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>43 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>44 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>45 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>46 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
            </Locations>
         </Valuation>
      </request>
   </Valuations>
   <Valuations>
      <request>
         <CompanyID>94A7DB70-F90F-4EE7-A614-E548D1045277</CompanyID>
         <Logon>ydahmouni</Logon>
         <CalculateValuation>true</CalculateValuation>
         <ReturnAddedValuation>true</ReturnAddedValuation>
         <Valuation>
            <Locations>
               <location>
                  <Address>
                     <Street>Stewart Place</Street>
                     <Line1>47 Stewart Place</Line1>
                     <country>US</country>
                  </Address>
               </location>
            </Locations>
         </Valuation>
      </request>
   </Valuations>
</provider-request>
```

Comment: See if you can adapt this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908488/xslt-for-each-wrapping-every-nth-item-in-a-div).

Comment: Hi Joel,Thanks a lot for your reply i managed to complete the xslt as required with the help of the link provided.