# CSS How to auto break/enter after n Div with display table-cell

Tags: html, css

Example I have 6 div with `display: table-cell`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37g8p3dp/)

HTML

```
<div class="widget">
  <div class="subWidget">
    A
  </div>

  <div class="subWidget">
    B
  </div>

  <div class="subWidget">
    C
  </div>

  <div class="subWidget">
    D
  </div>

  <div class="subWidget">
    E
  </div>

  <div class="subWidget">
    F
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.widget
{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 20px;
}

.widget .subWidget
{
  display: table-cell;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And now I want, every 5 div it will be break/enter the div 6th - 10th

Please see below

```
A | B | C | D | E
F
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it in table layout, use flexbox or float instead.

Comment: Any example for it ?

Comment: With float clear on `:nth-child(5n+1)` - https://jsfiddle.net/u6n9fxj1/

Answer (score 2):

To keep it simple, you need to add a row after every five column.
For every 5th div(which is a child) of widget `$(".widget :nth-child(5n)")`
Create a new div element as with style display as table-row. After every fifth element append it!

```
$(".widget :nth-child(5n)").each(function(){
        var $newRow=$("<div>").css("display","table-row");
            $(this).after($newRow);
});
```

**Edit: A better solution to add new rows!**

You can create a jquery function that wraps every 5th element with a row.

```
var $newRow=$("<div>").css("display","table-row");
$.fn.wrapEvery = function( cLen, wrapperEl ) {
    while ( this.length ) {
        $( this.splice(0, cLen) ).wrapAll( wrapperEl );
    }
};
$('.subWidget').wrapEvery(5, $newRow);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696975/wrapping-a-div-around-every-three-divs)

Here is the fiddle!

```js
var $newRow=$("<div>").css("display","table-row");

$.fn.wrapEvery = function( cLen, wrapperEl ) {
    while ( this.length ) {
        $( this.splice(0, cLen) ).wrapAll( wrapperEl );
    }
};

$('.subWidget').wrapEvery(5, $newRow);
```

```css
.widget
{
  display: table;
  //display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 20px;
}

.widget .subWidget
{
  display: table-cell;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget">

  <div class="subWidget">
    A
  </div>
  
  <div class="subWidget">
    B
  </div>
  
  <div class="subWidget">
    C
  </div>
  
  <div class="subWidget">
    D
  </div>
  
  <div class="subWidget">
    E
  </div>
  
  <div class="subWidget">
    F
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: if you feel that an answer is right for your question kindly accept it as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if this is able to be done with a "display: table-cell" - but you can achieve this with Flexbox quite easily:

```css
.widget
{
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 20px;
}

.widget .flexWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.widget .subWidget
{
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(20% - 1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="widget">
  <div class="flexWrap">
    <div class="subWidget">
      A
    </div>

    <div class="subWidget">
      B
    </div>

    <div class="subWidget">
      C
    </div>

    <div class="subWidget">
      D
    </div>

    <div class="subWidget">
      E
    </div>

    <div class="subWidget">
      F
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added a "FlexWrap" div so that you can control your Flex Content. Each child item will take-up 20%-1px of their flexbox (the -1px is to accommodate for your 1px border).

With this setup, you can have 5 items going across your with every 6th starting on a new row